# Can we auto pause animate() and resume() in setInterval function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I am trying to give Jquery image animation using `.setInterval()` and `.animate()` function in jquery. My code as follows:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){ 
   setInterval(function(){         
   $("#animate1").fadeIn('slow').animate({'margin-left':'220px','margin-bottom':'20px'},2000,function(){ 
   $('.1st').animate({'opacity':'0'},1000,function(){$('.1st').animate({'opacity':'1'}) })
   }).fadeOut();
   $("#animate1").fadeIn('slow').animate({'margin-bottom':'0px','margin-left':'-140px'},2000).fadeOut('slow');
  },2000);
    });
```

Now, I want to give animation in `$("#animate2")` but before it start I want that `$("#aniamte1")` to be stop or pause. So, catch is after `$("#animate1")` , I want that to stop/pause and run `$("#animate2")` and again after finish my `$("#animate2")` I want to pause/stop and run `$("#animate1")` . how can we done that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a variable when your animation finished.
As an example taken from the jQuery documentation (please format your code next time, it's hard to read):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var runAnimate1 = true;
   var runAnimate2 = false; 
   setInterval(function(){ 
      if(runAnimate1) {
        $( "#animate1").animate({
          width: [ "toggle", "swing" ],
          height: [ "toggle", "swing" ],
          opacity: "toggle"
        }, 5000, "linear", function() {
          runAnimate1 = false;
          runAnimate2 = true;
        });
      }

      if(runAnimate2) {
        $( "#animate2").animate({
         width: [ "toggle", "swing" ],
         height: [ "toggle", "swing" ],
         opacity: "toggle"
        }, 5000, "linear", function() {
          runAnimate1 = true;
          runAnimate2 = false;
       });
     }
   });
});
```

Something like that should work. Consider it as pseudo code, I haven't tested it but you should get the idea. You just need to adopt your animations and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks..!! fatel ..it works.. only you need to add  });

Comment: Great! I've added the missing brackets. :)